# how to show full screen page curl in harism demo

Tags: android, page-curl

I am trying to show the page curl effect on images on full screen in harism demo but couldn't find any solution for that, does anyone know how to show the effect on full screen images in harism demo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's this **harism demo**?

Comment: its open source for 3D page curl   https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inside CurlView.java

```
 public void setMargins(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    mRenderer.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
```

> Set Activity's theme to be full screen like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".CurlActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Just did it, anyways thanks a lot for your support Santosh :)